# Gulp inject not working one way but works the other - no difference is there?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-inject

I have a gulp task to inject bower components into my index.html file. I have 2 different versions of it and one works and one does not and I can't tell why the one does not work b/c it looks exactly the same to me.

Does NOT work

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

/**
 * Injects all the bower dependencies into index.html
 */
gulp.task('inject-bower-files', function() {
  return 
    gulp.src('./index.html')
      .pipe(inject(gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {read: false})))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Works

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

/**
 * Injects all the bower dependencies into index.html
 */
gulp.task('inject-bower-files', function() {

  var target = gulp.src('./index.html');
  var sources = gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {read: false});

  return target.pipe(inject(sources))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is failing due to JavaScript's [automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion).

It is equivalent to

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

/**
 * Injects all the bower dependencies into index.html
 */
gulp.task('inject-bower-files', function() {
  return; // <-- semicolon inserted here, nothing below this runs
    gulp.src('./index.html')
      .pipe(inject(gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {read: false})))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

To make it work, change it to

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

/**
 * Injects all the bower dependencies into index.html
 */
gulp.task('inject-bower-files', function() {
  // return is no longer on a line by itself
  return gulp.src('./index.html')
      .pipe(inject(gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {read: false})))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: Aka `ASI`. Might as well put some linter in that gulp task now, OP. :)

Comment: Ironically I actually have an eslint task but it wasn't working correctly for the same exact reason.